# What is the bigO of an algorithm that doubles with each added n?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Just something I observed with some code I wrote:

```
n = 24, time = 3s
n = 25, time = 6s
n = 26, time = 12s
n = 27, time = 24s
n = 28, time = 48s
```

Just looking at this number, what is the bigO of this code? I wanna say 2*n, but we know that the constant does not matter. Is it just O(n)? It doesn't look like it.

Edit: 2^N?

Comment: This question is not well-formed, because so many things could be affecting your running time, e.g. some resource throttling you each time you call it.  Yes, it _appears_ that it might vary with `2^N`, but we don't really know this for certain.  And the time also doubled for `n = 25`, casting doubt.

Comment: May be you mean `n = 24` at first line.

Comment: If you wrote the code, why do you want to guess the complexity from samples of the runtime for small n? Surely you already know what it does and don't have to guess?

Comment: yes, @RafafTahsin thanks for the typo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you mean `time(n) = time(n-1) * 2` ?

Yah, that's **`time(n) = 2^n`**

Answer (score 6):

```
t(n) = 2*t(n-1) = 2*(2*t(n-2)) = 2*2*t(n-2) = 2*2*2t(n-3) = 2^i*t(n-i)

t(n) = 2^n*t(n-n) = 2^n*t(0) = 2^n
```